# Trouble loading assembly: 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common'

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, exception, runtime-error

I have a VS 2008 solution whose projects are making use of a number of the Microsoft.Practicies libraries.

**Versions for all of the assemblies are: 4.1.x

**Everything builds fine, but when I run it, I get the following runtime error:**

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

**There are no versions of the enterprise library installed on the machine where the building and running is taking place.**

"Copy Local" is *true*, and "Specific Version" is *false* for all assemblies.

What am I doing wrong here?

Related: [Could not load file or assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431220/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-practices-enterpriselibrary-common-o), [Force Visual Studio References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149359/how-to-force-visual-studio-to-reference-local-enterprise-library-dll-file-instea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft practices libraries are tightly coupled, and some of the assemblies are interdependant. Make sure that you have added all the libraries you need, plus any additional library dependencies

Comment: which dependent assemblies to add @nav ?