# CefSharp.dll unresolved assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, dll, cefsharp, spotfire

I'm currently making an extension for Spotfire that embeds a web browser (CefSharp) into the application. However, when I attempt to run the package, I get the error:

"Package 'D3Visualizations' has unresolved assembly references:
  'CefSharp, version 1.25.4.0' is referenced by 'D3Visualizations.dll'."

I've added CefSharp.dll and CefSharp.WinForms.dll as references, and I have added those two as well as icudt.dll and libcef.dll into the bin/Debug folder.

I honestly don't know why it doesn't work right now; the last time I got an error in the package builder like this, it was due to .NET version mismatches.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express Desktop, and the project is in .NET framework 4.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the path for the references in their properties window? You can try removing and re-adding the references to the dlls in your bin folder and set Copy Local = true. If that doesn't work try setting it explicitly in the project file as in this question: [Force VS to reference local dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149359/how-to-force-visual-studio-to-reference-local-enterprise-library-dll-file-instea)